# android studio 3, how to configure sdk version

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to set the sdk installed version on my pc: sdk 19. I've got an error:

```
Error:Failed to find target with hash string 'android-25' in: /Users/myuser/Library/Android/sdk
<a href="install.android.platform">Install missing platform(s) and sync project</a>
```

Where is the file where I have to set the sdk version, min or max  ? Not the folder of sdk

the project come from an Ionic 3 project.

I've changed the file ./AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

./project properties:

target=android-19

And finally I change on Android Studio   menu "File" - "Project Structure" , Tab "Properties" ,

Fields:

```
"Compile sdk version"  = "API 19 Android 4.42"
"Build Tools version" = 26.0.0
```

but the errors keeps....

Answer (score 1):

*Where is the file where I have to set the sdk ?*
**Anyplace you prefer too**

*What SDK version should I use?*
**Depends in your audiences**

Make sure your SDK location is referred to where you downloaded it.
[image: SDK location]

Comment: Not really Android SDK location, but the file for config what sdk version it will be used the compiler

Comment: Well then, its your compileSdk. What vrsion you put in?

Comment: I've setted up '"Compile sdk version"  = "API 19 Android 4.42"  but compiler is asking me for android-25

Comment: Just put 19 for the value, no need API or Android version.